# Gatling - Extract Json value from previews request

Tags: gatling, scala-gatling

I'm new in Gatling, and trying to get value from json key.

This check give me labels:

```
.check(jsonPath("$[1].ppp[1].label").saveAs("label"))
```

In this request i got all json data like this

```
[
  {
    "id":258,
    "code":"D00CC3056",
    "label":"Test-0"
  },
  {
    "id":260,
    "code":"D00RR148",
    "label":"Test-1"
  }
]
```

From this Json, i need to get code value from a specific label, to use it in request after.

Something like : get code where label is "Test-1".

I've trying this but doesn't works:

```
        .exec(
            http("request_3:GET_/api/code")
            .get("/api/code")
            .check(status.is(200))
            .check(jsonPath("$..[*].code").find("{$label}").saveAs("code"))
        )
```

I don't know how to do this.

Any help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [JMESPath](https://jmespath.org/) that you should really learn and that Gatling supports:

```scala
.check(jmesPath("[?label == 'Test-1'].code").saveAs("code"))
```

Comment: Thanks that's a good idea.

Last point, i've tried this 

```
 .check(jmesPath("[?label == '${customerCodeList}'].code").saveAs("code"))
```

But doesn't works, it's seems that ${customerCodeList} doesn't convert data ? missing something?

Comment: found the way for doing this .check(jmesPath("[?label == '${label}'].code").saveAs["code"])